# Why does rounding off the mol values when finding an empirical formula lead to a different result?

Tags: stoichiometry

The question I was doing tells you that the compound consist of 49.0% carbon, 2.7% of hydrogen ,and 48.2% of chlorine. And ask you to find the empirical formula.

I did the usual procedure of dividing the percentages by each elements atomic mass. Because the result for carbon was 4.0796, I thought I should rounding to four moles of carbon. And for hydrogen and chlorine the numbers of mole for each are 3 and 1.  I want to check the formula is correct, so I make it 8 moles of carbon, but then the number of mole for hydrogen turns out to be 5 and chlorine 3.

Now there is a new empirical formula. Which one is correct?

PC: when I divided the percentages by atomic mass, I rounded the results to ten thousandth place.
[image]

Comment: Nope, not exact same

Comment: Please show us how you got 3 for Cl and 1 for H.

Comment: 3 for H actually

Comment: Actually, it would be better to see *all* your work on the problem.

Comment: There u go, LDC3

Comment: To me, it looks like 4, 2 2/3 and 1 1/3. So after multiplying by 3 should give you the integer ratios of the 3 elements.

Comment: But it's not whole number ratio.

Comment: Please don't title your posts something like "Help me correct my mistake."  Taking a little bit of time to come up with a title that encompasses what the post is about will help people find it.

Comment: Sure they are `after multiplying by 3`: $4\times 3=12, 2\frac{2}{3}\times 3=8$ and $1\frac {1}{3}\times 3=4$. You should now divide by 4 to get a reduced ratio.

Comment: 1) The concept in the linked question is the same, so it more than qualifies as a duplicate. And if you would have read the answers carefully and followed the step by step instructions, you would have arrived at LDC3's answer. 2) It would have been helpful if you at least rotated the image if you do not want to type up a few numbers again. This way no one has to stretch his/her neck out of the natural way...